# How to Search text and replace text on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Search text and replace text on button click in jquery(e.g- In visual studio if we press ctrl + f then a box open, there is a option of replacing the text, I want same like visual studio). But only using Javascript or Jquery

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: ya i tried window.find for find text option, but for replace the text.. i didn't find any thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there's a plugin created for that: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

Comment: Is there any other way(without plugin)..?